# How to create a confidence ellipse with weights?

Tags: graph, stata, ellipse, weighted, weighted-graph

I would like to draw a confidence ellipse (sometimes also called concentration ellipse) for two continuous variables using Stata.

There is a *community-contributed* command called `ellip` for this kind of graph, a detailed description of which is provided by its author Anders Alexandersson on [Stata Journal](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr32_1). However, I would like to apply weights for the ellipse which is not possible using this command.

Below is a reproducible example where I try to plot the number of marriages per `1000` inhabitants over the percentage of urban population in US states using the population size as a weight:

```
clear all
sysuse census

gen marpop = marriage / pop * 1000
gen urbpop = popurban / pop * 100

ellip marpop urbpop if state2!="NV", plot(scatter marpop urbpop if state2!="NV") ///
    name(ellip_noaw)
ellip marpop urbpop if state2!="NV", plot(scatter marpop urbpop [aw=pop] if state2!="NV") ///
    name(ellip_aw)

graph combine ellip_noaw ellip_aw
```

The results look as follows:

[image: Confidence ellipse example]

As you can see the second ellipse, where the points of the scatter plot are weighted/inflated by the population size, should be possibly shifted to the bottom-right.

How can I create a weighted confidence ellipse in Stata?

Comment: You will need to write your own program for that or alter the source code of `ellip`.

Comment: Yes, @PearlySpencer  I probably have to rewrite parts of `ellip`. But I am not sure where to start as I do not know whether the formula used by Alexandersson (2004: 253-254) holds for weighted data. If @anders-alexandersson is the author of the ado, he might have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: I think writing to the author of the command is your best bet. Your question on here is unlikely to get an answer as would require a lot of effort for someone and non-programming expertise in this area to come up with the solution.